# Excel document - I want a cell to change colour depending on several conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have cell F1 that I want to change colour depending on other cell conditions:

F1 GREEN if cells B1 & D1 are both blank;

F1 ORANGE if cell B1 has text but D1 blank;

F1 RED if cell D1 has text

Is this possible??
Thanks!

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-macro-color-code-based-on-input-formula-or/67305338-3c10-49a3-b11e-caab899b9346

Comment: either the above, or if VBA isn't your thing use [conditional formatting](https://www.excel-university.com/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Condiftional Formatting, select **F1** go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **Manager Rules...**- **New Rule**- **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**:
[image]
Then you can enter the formuls for different conditions:

Green: `=AND($B$1=0,$D$1=0)`

Orange: `=AND($B$1<>0,$D$1=0)`

Red: `=AND($B$1=0,$D$1<>0)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is is brilliant and worked a treat.